# Smartgwt - How to differentiate between the FilterEditorSubmitHandler source?

Tags: java, filter, smartgwt, listgrid

Using smartgwt (version:v9.0_2013-07-03)
In the listgrid , is there anyway to differentiate between when the FilterEditorSubmitHandler event is fired due to the filter button clicked or enter key & due to the filter key press??

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way to do it. SmartGWT API also doesn't provide any such functionality as per the best of my knowledge. You can do some manual stuff to achieve this. See the below code snippet.

```
boolean isKeyPressed = true;
grid.setFilterOnKeypress(false);

grid.addFilterEditorSubmitHandler(new FilterEditorSubmitHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onFilterEditorSubmit(FilterEditorSubmitEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Enter: " + isKeyPressed);
        if (!isKeyPressed) {
            isKeyPressed = true;
        }
    }
});

Button button = new Button();
button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        isKeyPressed = false;
        grid.filterByEditor();
    }
});
grid.setFilterButtonProperties(button);
```

Hope it helps you.